# Google-api and tokens or how do i get a token for google affiliate advertiser list (ruby)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, google-api, google-api-client

I try to get my advertisers list from GAN (in a ruby app), so I need to get first a token.

I tried in many ways, include ruby gems, but didn't get it.

Does someone know the exact way how to get this token?